# Is $5^2-3^2=16$ the only example for $(P_n)^2 - (P_{n-1})^2 \bmod 6 ≠ 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

Is $5^2-3^2=16$ the only example for $(P_n)^2 - (P_{n-1})^2 \bmod 6 ≠ 0$ where $P$ is an element of the consecutive list of prime numbers (without $2$): ${3,5,7,11,13,17...P_n}$

As a web developer and a self math learner, out of curiosity I have created a script to find the difference between a prime number its previous prime number on a consecutive list.

From the first $100000$ primes, Starting with $5^2-3^2=16$, only $5^2-3^2=16$ was not divisible by $6$.

Is it proven to be the case (Yes being divisible by $6$) for all the remaining differences, and if so what makes  only $5^2-3^2=16$ act different?

The only thing that stands out for me is that $5$ is the only prime ending in $5$, I wish I could post my own ideas for what I think might be  the cause, but I really don't have a clue, so any help is appreciated.

Attached you can see a screen shot of the first results:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. First, we claim that every prime $>3$ is congruent to $\pm 1 \bmod{6}$. This is easy to see since a prime bigger than $3$ cannot be congruent to $0,2,3,4 \bmod{6}$ since it would then be divisible by either $2$ or $3$, which is impossible.

Next, assume that $p_{n-1}>3$. Then,
$$p_{n-1} \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{6} \implies p_{n-1}^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{6}$$
Similarly, since $p_n>p_{n-1}>3$, we have $p_n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{6}$. This shows that $p_n^2-p_{n-1}^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{6}$. Now, the only possibility where this does not hold where $p_n$ and $p_{n-1}$ are odd primes, is when $p_{n-1}=3$ and hence, $5^2-3^2=16$ is the only exception to the observation.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

For any prime $q>3,q=6p\pm1$ where $p$ is any integer

$$\implies q^2=24p^2+24\cdot\dfrac{p(p\pm1)}2+1\equiv1\pmod{24}$$

Comment: +1. Minor criticism : since $p$ is not necessarily a prime, I wouldn't have called it $p$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy, Agreed. $p$ is conventionally taken for a prime, though I mentioned clearly its nature here!